# How to fix error: Cant find variable document when I run react vis network in android?

Tags: react-native, react-vis-network

I know that exist other questions like this, but I didn't find any question like this related with react-vis-network, none of the answers that I found solve my problem.

I am trying to use react vis network in android, but when I run my error I get the error message "can't find variable document when evaluating react-vis-network".

How can I fix this?

My code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Network, Node, Edge } from 'react-vis-network';

export default class MyNetwork extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Network>
        <Node id="vader" label="Darth Vader" />
        <Node id="luke" label="Luke Skywalker" />
        <Node id="leia" label="Leia Organa" />
        <Edge id="1" from="vader" to="luke" />
        <Edge id="2" from="vader" to="leia" />
      </Network>
    );
  }
}
```

I thank you in advance.